# Chrome Extensions: portId_ missing from the port object

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am using the `chrome.runtime.port` to connect to the background script. But for some users somehow the **portId_** is missing from the **port** object. The weird thing is that its missing from some users not all. Any help would be appreciated.!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that they took out portId_ in chrome version 34. So some users are using the latest version of chrome and the others don't, but they are going to face the problem as soon as they update to the latest one.